# R script for calculating percentages over several files into new column

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
NCNC    413
JJNC    183
```

I would like to add another column of data such that it gives in percentage: `the percent NCNC and JJNC values.`

Ideally, I would like to know how to apply this script to several files in a folder. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add more observations along with the code you have written?

Comment: @Metrics: I haven't used any code really. We are getting these numbers from a tagged corpus of text. Col 1 lists the tags. We would like to add up Col 2, and output should be:- (Col 2/Sum of Col 2)*100. We would like to do this with several files in a folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have to make a lot of assumptions here because you haven't been very clear about your specific situation. If you've set your working directory to where the files are located, and they're csv files, the following may work for you. There are many factors that could stop it working though, so if it doesn't, you may have to get back with more detail.

```
#Get list of all files in the folder
files <- list.files("./", ".csv")
#Make a function to read in a file, produce the percent column
perc.fun <- function(x) {
  dat <- read.csv(x, head = FALSE)
  dat$perc <- dat[,2]/sum(dat[,2])
  write.table(dat, paste("perc", x, sep = "_"), sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
}
#Use lapply to go through the list of files and apply the function
lapply(files, perc.fun)
```

The output files should be in the same folder with `perc_` in front of the old filename. If you have headers in your files, then you'll need to modify to account for that.